# Going from insert to normal in vim causes this to appear

Tags: vim

Whenever I go from insert to normal mode, this shows up at the bottom of my vim screen.
What is it and how do I stop it?
[image: What is this madness?]

[image]

Comment: What does the output of `:verbose autocmd InsertLeave` show?

Comment: OP changed to include output

Comment: Okay, the listed file in the output is doing something weird--it looks like it might have been corrupted somehow.  Try moving it out of the way.

Comment: That file is my colorscheme, but I'll do it

Comment: Looks like a fix, thanks. It was a "colorscheme template" I had downloaded that must have been messed up by whoever made it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have some odd autocommands that are triggering on the `InsertLeave` event.  To see what they are and identify where they are set you can do this:

```
:verbose autocmd InsertLeave
```

Then you can remove or correct the problematic Vim script.

Lots of information about autocommands can be read by doing:

```
:help autocmd.txt
```